# How do I upgrade Java Compiler?

Tags: java, jcreator

I'm using JCreator to work with Java. I got this exception (or maybe error?) it says the following:

> major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
>   It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.

I downloaded the last version of Java SE, but that didn't work.

By the way, Java files compile fine and also run without any problem. But I have downloaded a file that my instructor has upload with many java classes and this message appears when I try to run the class that has the main method.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic.  IMO, this should be migrated to super-user.  It is really about how to install / upgrade a software tool, rather than about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used JCreator, but a little bit of Googling gave me [this page of JCreator  installation instructions](http://www.jcreator.com/installation.htm), which has the following instructions for manually setting the JDK that JCreator uses:

- Starting JCreator Without Using the Setup Wizard
- With JCreator active, open the Options window from the Configure menu.
- Click the JDK Profiles option.
- Click the default item in the list, and click Edit.
- Ensure that the Name field shows the correct version of the selected JDK directory; in this case, JDK version jdk1.6.0.  *[ That's a typo I think ... ]*
- Set the JDK Home path by clicking the Browse button next to this field.
- Browse to the root directory of the JDK installation: C:..\jdk1.7.0. Click OK.
- Click the Documentation tab, and Add the path: C:..\jdk1.7.0\docs. Click OK.
- Close the windows.

Yours is a slightly different scenario, but I think these instructions should also work for changing the JDK for an existing installation of JCreator.

<sub>(Use the pathnames of your latest JDK installation ... obviously.)</sub>